# How to sort and color pointranges in plot with facet grid and position dodge?

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, colors, facet

I have a facet gridded plot of two groups of fixed effects models. In group one I want to suppress the control variable (shown green). In group two I want to show the control variables if there is one in the model with a `position_dodgev()`.

So far I figured out this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)
ggplot(mf, aes(fill=mn)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0) +
  geom_pointrangeh(aes(y=mn, x=coef, group=cv, color=cv, 
                       xmin=coef - se*1.96, xmax=coef + se*1.96),
                   position=position_dodgev(.5),
                   show.legend=FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("green", "red", "green", "red")) +
  facet_grid(gr ~ ., scales="free", space="free")
```

which gives me this:

[image]

However, in model 1 the explanatory variable is duplicated and the explanatory variable in the models of group 2 are not always on top.

I actually want to look the plot like this (photoshopped):

[image]

How would that be possible with `ggplot()`?

---

#### *Data*

```
mf <- structure(list(coef = c(3.025, 0.762499999999999, -1.44237073106609, 
-0.125042600081792, -0.689108910891089, 2.64264321029771, 2.64264321029771
), se = c(5.26319027539381, 3.34469904756018, 2.02098677878979, 
2.02098677878979, 2.02098677878979, 0.763989041657158, 0.763989041657158
), mn = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Model 2c", 
"Model 2b", "Model 2a", "Model 1"), class = "factor"), gr = c(2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1), cv = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L
), .Label = c("gear", "vs", "disp"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("vs", 
"gear", "vs1", "disp", "1", "11", "2"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Not essential to the question, but a tip on keeping things minimal: do we need all the code in this last section that creates `mf` in order to solve the problem? If not, you can cut it and just give us `dput(mf)`. +1 regardless

Comment: You also might be interested in [`GGally::ggcoef`](https://ggobi.github.io/ggally), might make this a little easier

Comment: @camille You're absolutely right -> edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few small changes to your data will help fix the plot.  First, we can remove the duplicated row for Model 1.  Second, the issues with your cv colors changing order is that you have different control variables between Models 2a and 2b.  We can create a indicator column to simply say whether or not the row is a control variable, and use that to color the plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggstance)

mf %>% 
  #remove the dupe from Model 1
  filter(!(mn == "Model 1" & cv == "disp")) %>% 
  #create an indicator column for control variables
  mutate(Control = cv == "vs") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill=mn)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0) +
  #group and color using our new indicator variable
  geom_pointrangeh(aes(y=mn, x=coef, group=Control, color=Control, 
                       xmin=coef - se*1.96, xmax=coef + se*1.96),
                   position=position_dodgev(.5),
                   show.legend=FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("green", "red", "green", "red")) +
  facet_grid(gr ~ ., scales="free", space="free")
```

[image: final plot]